# Как найти ID строки по одному из ее элементов?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDB";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";
    public static final String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID
        + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_SURNAME + " text," + KEY_LOGIN + " text," + KEY_PASSWORD + " text" + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)
    {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

Известно, как при помощи Cursor найти что-то по ID. А как мне сделать наоборот - по логину найти этот ID?

Comment: Забудь про курсоры

Comment: и что тогда следует использовать?

Comment: оператор SELECT

Comment: Точно также. Просто вместо `where _id=` указать `where login=`. Покажите как вы ищете по id.

Comment: Можно то же самое, но не в комментах, а в виде полноценного ответа? Я новичок по части sqlite в android и не совсем понимаю все это.

Comment: Это не ответ а направление вам, в какую сторону двигаться. Ещё раз, вы пишите "Известно, как при помощи Cursor найти что-то по ID." Покажите, как вы ищете по id.